# Toolbox/Podman Alternative for MacOS

Tags: software-recommendation, development, docker

I primarily develop on Linux and recently bought a Macbook, and am looking to make the development experience familiar to what I am used to. Note that this focuses on work native to the OS, rather than working over SSH which I have no problems with.

One way I used to deal with lack of package support on a Linux distro was to use [Toolbox](https://github.com/containers/toolbox) with `Arch Linux`, and keep development packages in a container.

This is what I would like to do with macOS as well. I have a `podman` setup on macOS but the `Toolbox` tool seems very specific to Linux. Is there a somewhat equivalent tool for mac?

I don't need desktop integration, and only need CLI packages and libraries. I am also willing to manually write `podman-compose` files if no such tool exists.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me, what your problem with "package support" specifically is. Perhaps your needs could be met simply by installing [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh).

If that is not the case, you might want to look at [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) instead.

Comment: There is podman support with HomeBrew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/podman#default

Comment: @agarza It is written in the question that he already has podman installed, so that's probably not going to help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. I already have brew installed, and used it to install podman. I also am aware of macports and nix as other options. I am focused more on certain packages unavailable in macos/brew. I am aware of Vagrant but will look into that more as an option, thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what those packages are?